# Is there a list of Azure services supported by Azure Resource Manager?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Is there a list of Azure services that can be initiated by Azure Resource Manager templates?

And are there sample templates available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a list of Azure services that can be initiated by Azure
> Resource Manager templates?

Almost every service in Azure can be initiated by ARM templates. Only exceptions are the services that have "Classic" in their name (Classic Storage Account, Classic Cloud Service for example).

> And are there sample templates available?

You can find the sample templates (at least the schema and some quick start templates) for all Azure Services here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/.